# Json as String inside another Json using SimpleJson c#

Tags: c#, json, string

I need to parse the following Json

```
{
    "type": "send",
    "data": "{"window":"true", "shell":"true", "wait":"false"}",
    "tag": ""
}
```

I want data to be interpreted as a simple string:

```
"{"window":"true", "shell":"true", "wait":"false"}"
```

not as a json inside a json. How sholud I escape it?

Comment: *Why* would you want to do that?

Comment: You need to detect the Key which has the other json value that you want as a string and then do a toString()

Comment: Ist part of a server code. It has to send the data part as a string. Some clients receive simple string but some might need to receive strings that happends to be a json.

Comment: To detect the Key I should modify the Parse function, right?

Comment: How do you know that the value of key should be a json? Is data always gonna have json?

Comment: No, it usually isn't a json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. The easiest thing to do is generate the json with simple json instead of doing it by hand.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    "type": "send",
    "data": '{"window":"true", "shell":"true", "wait":"false"}',
    "tag": ""
}
```

The corresponding class generated by [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/)

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string data { get; set; }
    public string tag { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I used to use Json.NET that for what I see, I imagine is something like json2csharp. The thing is that the ones that generate the json use simple json.

Comment: json2csharp is what i could do for a sample, as it generates classes from JSON. Yes this will work with Json.NET as both work on the same principle.

Comment: That principle is exactly what I don't want. With Json.NET I had the same problem I'm haveing now.